# Как передать логин пользователя в таблицу? C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно, чтобы после входа в аккаунт, при добавлении товара в корзину, логин пользователя автоматически добавлялся в таблицу с заказами. Подскажите, как это реализовать? Я делала так, но у меня передаётся всё в таблицу заказов, кроме самого логина.

Первая форма - вход пользователя.

```
    public string userlog;
<...>
private void EnterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Авторизация пользователя
        {
           <...> //цикл на проверку
                        else if (sdr[4].ToString() == "user")
                        {
                            userlog = LoginBox.Text;
                            ProductInfo pi = new ProductInfo();
                            pi.ulog = userlog;

                            MainForm mf = new MainForm();
                            this.Hide();
                            mf.Show();                           
                        }
           <...> //цикл на проверку
        }
```

Вторая форма - добавление в корзину

```
public string ulog;

    private void AddToBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DateTime AddingDate = DateTime.Now;
       double totalPrice = Convert.ToDouble(CounterProd.Value) * Convert.ToDouble(ProdPrice.Text);

        if (CounterProd.Value <= Convert.ToInt32(ProdAmount.Text))
        {

            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=R500V\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=drug-store;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders]
       ([UserLogin]
       ,[ProductName]
       ,[Amount]
       ,[Date]
       ,[TotalPrice]
       ,[UserAdress]
       ,[Status])
 VALUES
       ('" + ulog + "','" + ProdName.Text + "','" + CounterProd.Value + "','" + AddingDate + "','" + totalPrice + "', ' ', 'В корзине')", connect);
            connect.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
```

Может можно каким-то другим способом передать значение логина? Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема!

Answer (score 1):

Вы не передаёте значение `ulog` во 2-ю форму - только в экземпляр класса `ProductInfo`, также у вас некорректное сравнение:

```cs
    public string userlog;
<...>
private void EnterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Авторизация пользователя
        {
            const userLoginPrefix = "user";

           <...> //цикл на проверку
                        else if (sdr.StartsWith(userLoginPrefix)) // replaced line
                        {
                            userlog = LoginBox.Text;
                            ProductInfo pi = new ProductInfo();
                            pi.ulog = userlog;

                            MainForm mf = new MainForm();
                            mf.ulog = userlog; // added line
                            this.Hide();
                            mf.Show();                           
                        }
           <...> //цикл на проверку
        }
```

---

Пожалуйста, пишите код по code-style данного языка (в данном случае c#):

- `ulog`, `userlog` -> `userLogin`
- `public string ulog` -> `internal string userLogin`
- `pi` -> `productInfo` / `product`
- `ProdName`, ... -> `ProductName`, ...
- `sdr` -> ???
- `a.ToStirng() + ", " + b.ToString()` -> `$"{a}, {b}"` / билдинг с использованием `StringBuilder` / `ValueStringBuilder` ([ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/company/clrium/blog/418911/))